# How to add a row of coefficients to a matrix and compute differences between rows using sympy and fractions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math, sympy

```py
import sympy as sp
from fractions import Fraction

M = sympy.symbols('M')

#It is called output, but in reality it is because the matrix is obtained 
# from a previous process, although it would be the input of this process.
output = [['B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2'], 
          [5*M + 3, 3, 5*M/2 - 3/2, 3/2 - 3*M/2, -M, M/2 - 3/2, M, 3/2 - M/2]]

z_function = "Z = 3 * X1 + 2 * X2 + 1 * X3 + 0 * X4 + 0 * X5 + M * U1 + M * U2"
```

I must add a row of the coefficients in the expression of `z_function`. Keep in mind that with coefficients I mean the numerical values that multiply the variables in a mathematical expression

Note that the coefficient of the expression corresponding to the column variable is placed inside the matrix, and if there is no associated coefficient (as is the case of `B`) then it will simply place `None`

```py
output = [['B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2'], 
          [5*M + 3, 3, 5*M/2 - 3/2, 3/2 - 3*M/2, -M, M/2 - 3/2, M, 3/2 - M/2], 
          [None, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, M, M]]
```

Then using `sympy` with `sp.sympify()` or/and using `fractions` with `Fraction().limit_denominator()` compute the difference between row index 1 and row index 2, and add the results in a new row with index 3, this as long as none of the cells to be subtracted is `None`

```
(5*M + 3) - (None) = None
(3) - (3) = 0
(5*M/2 - 3/2) - (2) = 5*M/2 - 5/2
(3/2 - 3*M/2) - (1) = 1/2 - 3*M/2
(-M) - (0) = -M
(M/2 - 3/2) - (0) = M/2 - 3/2
(M) - (M) = 0
(3/2 - M/2) - (M) = 3/2 - 3*M/2
```

The array should look like this:

```py
output = [[    'B', 'X1',        'X2',        'X3', 'X4',      'X5', 'U1',        'U2'], 
          [5*M + 3,    3, 5*M/2 - 3/2, 3/2 - 3*M/2,   -M, M/2 - 3/2,    M,   3/2 - M/2], 
          [   None,    3,           2,           1,    0,         0,    M,           M], 
          [   None,    0, 5*M/2 - 5/2, 1/2 - 3*M/2,   -M, M/2 - 3/2,    0, 3/2 - 3*M/2]]
```

Here my code, although it does not work correctly since it subtracts the coefficients of the columns, in addition to the fact that it does not perform the calculations between the boxes correctly

```py
# Add coefficient row to the output matrix
output.append([None] + [sp.sympify(term) if term != 'B' else None for term in output[0][1:]])

# Calculate the differences between the penultimate and last row
difference_row = [None] + [output[-2][i] - output[-1][i] if output[-2][i] is not None and output[-1][i] is not None else None for i in range(1, len(output[0]))]

# Add the difference row to the output matrix
output.append(difference_row)

print(output)
for row in output: print(row)
```

Comment: `sympy` has its own version of Fractions, `Rational` I believe it's called

Comment: @hpaulj I am using Fractions because the Sympy module gave me problems with the rounding of some operations, regardless of this code does not work correctly

Comment: What does the print of the initial `output` look like?

Comment: @hpaulj Initially I have the array `output = [['B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2'], [5*M + 3, 3, 5*M/2 - 3/2, 3/2 - 3*M/2, -M, M/2 - 3/2, M, 3/2 - M/2]]` then I add the row to it of coefficients at the end, and finally I add a row with the values obtained from subtracting from the values of this row `[5*M + 3, 3, 5*M/2 - 3/2, 3/2 - 3* M/2, -M, M/2 - 3/2, M, 3/2 - M/2]]` the values of the coefficient array `[None, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, M, M]`, which will result in a new row that I will place at the end.

Comment: When I display output, the 2nd row shows as: `[5*M + 3, 3, 5*M/2 - 1.5, 1.5 - 3*M/2, -M, M/2 - 1.5, M, 1.5 - M/2]`.  `M/2` .  There are no `Fraction` terms in that list.

Comment: @hpaulj I got the same result without going to decimals if I use the code from the answer, I've also tried using `diffs = [Fraction(float(val)).limit_denominator() if isinstance(val, float) else val for val in diffs]` at the end of the code but it doesn't work either.

Comment: `Fraction(2,3)` or `Rational(2,3)` is the proper use.  Keep the 2 terms separate.

Comment: @hpaulj implementing that on the output of the question is really complicated in order to get this `[None, 0, 5*M/2 - 5/2, 1/2 - 3*M/2, -M, M/2 - 3/ 2, 0, 3/2 - 3*M/2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do this:

```
In [34]: import sympy as sym
    ...:
    ...: M = sympy.symbols('M')
    ...:
    ...: output = [['B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2'],
    ...:           [5*M + 3, 3, 5*M/2 - sym.S(3)/2, sym.S(3)/2 - 3*M/2, -M, M/2 - sym.S(3)/2, M, sym.S(3)/2 - M/2]]
    ...:
    ...: z_function = "Z = 3 * X1 + 2 * X2 + 1 * X3 + 0 * X4 + 0 * X5 + M * U1 + M * U2"

In [35]: z = sym.parse_expr(z_function[3:])

In [36]: z
Out[36]: M⋅U₁ + M⋅U₂ + 3⋅X₁ + 2⋅X₂ + X₃

In [37]: coeffs = [z.coeff(s) if s in z_function else None for s in output[0]]

In [38]: coeffs
Out[38]: [None, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, M, M]

In [39]: diffs = [r1 - r2 if None not in (r1, r2) else None for r1, r2 in zip(output[1], coeffs)]

In [40]: diffs
Out[40]: [None, 0, 5*M/2 - 7/2, 1/2 - 3*M/2, -M, M/2 - 3/2, 0, 3/2 - 3*M/2]
```

The test `s in z_function` is just checking if a string is a substring of another. This is because you require to distinguish between `B` which is not in the string and `X4` which is in the string but has a coefficient of zero and that is just a convenient way to handle that case. Testing for a substring like that could fail if your variable names were overlapping though.

Comment: I got the result without going to decimals if I use the code from the answer, I've also tried using `diffs = [Fraction(float(val)).limit_denominator() if isinstance(val, float) else val for val in diffs]` at the end of the code but it doesn't work either. Some idea?